# Testing for differences across options in check all that apply question?

Tags: survey, group-differences

I have a survey question where I have asked respondents to check all that apply. There are three options. I would like to test if the percentage is significantly different between the three options. One person can appear across all three categories. So there is no assumption of independence. Is there a test I can apply?

Answer (score 0):

The simplistic answer depends on if the "AND" or the "OR" more important:

For example, if I ask the question "Which of these foods do you like? Pizza, Tacos, BBQ. Pick on or more." and the respondent marks  Tacos and BBQ, then I would record that response as $1/2$ vote for each. If the "OR" is important, then you really only have three categories, and each split vote should be counted fractionally.

However, I could have asked the question "Which of these foods would you like for lunch? Pizza, Tacos, BBQ. Pick on or more." If the respondent selects Tacos and BBQ for this question, we would have to find a restaurant that serves both. In this case, the "AND" is important, so  you must treat each possible combination as it's own response. For this type of question, we have seven total categories: (P, T, BBQ, P&T, P&BBQ, T&BBQ, P&T&BBQ).

The above is how I would work on a simple problem. If you are in need of more rigor or a very robust and defensible model, then I would treat the response as an $n \times 3$ correlated binary response matrix, and then use some sort of Multiple Binary Response model:
http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1998.10474100#.WjgDdlWnFhE